# grails and input tag for upload files in edit.gsp page

Tags: grails, input, upload, gsp

In my Grails project, I have a domain class that allows me to store some large files. It has the following structure:

```
class PatientMedicalArchive {

byte[] document1;
byte[] document2;
byte[] document3;

String descriptionDocument1;
String descriptionDocument2;
String descriptionDocument3;

static belongsTo = [patient:Patient, secUser:SecUser]

static constraints = {
    descriptionDocument1(maxSize: 255)
    descriptionDocument2(maxSize: 255)
    descriptionDocument3(maxSize: 255)
}

static mapping = {
    document1(sqlType: "longblob")
    document2(sqlType: "longblob")
    document3(sqlType: "longblob")
}
}
```

It allows me to store large files in database in correct way. The problem is that, when I need to edit one instance of this class, I need to fill the fields with the name of file uploaded. Is it possible? How can I do it?

Comment: This question is hard to understand. Do you have already controller logic able to load file from path stored in descriptionDocument string into document byte array? In edit.gsp, you want to specify file name and then load it into document? Or what is desired workflow?

Comment: When I edit an instance of this class, I don't see the name of the file into the form. I only have the browse button to choose a file, but I don't know which file I have selected when I create the instance. So, I need to know if there is a way to show the filename in the form in edit.gsp (with the browse button already present obviously) to let user know which file has been selected when he creates the instance.

Comment: There is no reference between document & descriptionDocument string in your PatientMedicalArchive class. I would prefer to create Document class, or similar. What will contain document longblob, description String etc. Then you can reference separate Document class instances from PatientMedicalArchive class, or List of this documents. Also CRUD gsps will be created only once, or you can create taglib to include Document class CRUD functionality to corresponding PatientMedicalArchive managing gsp. I thing this would be more transparent and easier to solve troubles.